# Driving 72 leds with 555 timer

Tags: led

I want to make a circuit with a 555 timer to run 72 LEDs all at the same time. I have already made a circuit, but am not sure If it will work safe and long or not. I am putting the picture of the circuit and I want anybody who can help to look at it and see if it needs some extra components. Please add them on the circuit or explain instructions to add.

[image]

Comment: Where is the picture?

Answer (score 12):

Your proposed circuit will not work. Let's say a single three LED string draws 20mA, then 24 strings in parallel will draw 24 × 20mA = 480mA.

Now take a look at the datasheet for a typical [555](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM555.pdf). Although the maximum output current for the 555 is not explicitly mentioned, the 'Low Output Voltage' parameter on page 3 is only spec'd up to 200mA. This means the 555 will not be able to higher sink currents than that.

What you need is a driver stage, a transistor that can be controlled by the 555 and can drive the required current. Simplest is to use a MOSFET, which is perfectly viable with a 12V supply voltage. Because you didn't mention the exact LED current, I can't propose a transistor part number, but the circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNzpSA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Actually the below may work too, but I can't test it. The discharge pin is open collector and inverted from the output pin. The MOSFET again inverts the signal, hence the BJT from the circuit above can be eliminated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsUIFs.png)</sup>

For selecting a proper transistor, look for I(D) being larger than the total expected LED current. Make sure you have some head room, maybe a factor 1.5 - 2 or more.

Comment: But now you need to somehow invert the polarity of the output of the 555 in order to get the same functionality.

Comment: @DaveTweed Good point, I didn't notice it wasn't configured as astabile multivibrator. I changed the circuit with an extra inverter stage.

Comment: I would use a little IGBT instead of the MOSFET

Comment: The maximum current of each LED line can be calculated from the source voltage (12V), minimum LED forward drop (3.2V) and current-limiting resistor value (82R) in OP's schematic: 12V - (3*3.2V) / 82 Ohms ~= 29mA

Comment: Better idea: divide the LEDs into, say, 8 groups, and use the 555 timer to generate a clock signal which drives some digital circuit (e.g. 8 bit shift register based thing) that rotates among the 8 groups.

Answer (score 2):

You have 25 parallel LED circuits. With a 12v supply, 82 ohm resistors, and Vfwd on the LEDS of about 3.5v the current in each circuit will be about 20mA.

25 circuits at 20mA is 500mA

I think the maximum current from a 555 is 200mA.

This circuit is stressing the 555, it probably will stop working soon.